# Performance loss in C++0x and static local variables?

Tags: multithreading, static, c++11

What is a realistic performance loss due to the fact that in C++0x *all other threads shall 
wait* in a case like this:

```
string& program_name() {
  static string instance = "Parallel Pi";
  return instance;
}
```

Lets assume the optimal scenario: The programmer was very careful that even with 100 threads only the *main thread* calls the function `program_name`, all the other 99 *worker threads* are busy doing useful stuff, which does not involve calling this "critical" function.

I quote from the new C++0x-Std [§ 6.7.(4) stmt.decl](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf)

> ...such an object is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration... If control enters the declaration concurrently while the object is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization...

What is a realistic overhead that a real-world compiler is needed to impose on me to ensure that that static initialization is done as required by the standard.

- Is a lock/mutex required? I assume they are expensive, even when not really needed?
- If they are expensive, will this be done by less expensive mechanisms?

edit: added `string`...

Comment: If you use a Singleton, you have problems. That's how it works.

Comment: IIRC, in one google video, one of the threads experts said that due to a new algorithm, initialization of local statics can and will be be done in serious C++0x implementations without locking in a thread safe manner.

Comment: I assume you mean `static string instance = ...;`.

Comment: @Johannes: Can you point me to that google video?

Answer (score 2):

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the object is being initialized, the
>   concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization...

I think this is reasonable and very normal thing to do in concurrent programming. Anyway, this statement doesn't say that all other threads must wait for this initialization. They have to wait **in case** they need to access the initializing object.

> Is a lock/mutex required? I assume they are expensive, even when not really needed?

Could be. Mutex / lock aren't **that** expensive actually, they're expensive only when the locked code fragment needs to be accessed frequently by many or even all threads.

> If they are expensive, will this be done by less expensive mechanisms?

There are also another non-lock based solutions AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

If you were really concerned about the price of the lock, you could simply call the function before you started your worker threads, which would initialise the static. If you call it after the threads start, either you or the compiler has got to arrange for locking of some sort, so there is no real extra overhead.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler have to add the synchronization logic to every local static anyway, just in case it is used from two threads at once?  Even if the compiler does flow analysis, I don't expect it to be able to prove anything for most cases, even if the flow of main leads directly to this without calling any functions from other compilation units, initialization of globals could start threads.  Sorry, I don't see how you avoid paying for the lock you don't need.

Comment: @Ben If the compiler does flow analysis, then it can definitely see there is only one thread of execution. Whether any will do so is I agree moot. However, if it isn't doing such analysis, *something* had better lock that static in an MT environment.

Comment: @Neil: I want to understand what happens in general. Sure, calling the function once would get rid of the initialization during "real runtime". As Ben pointed out, I assume there would be some overhead for the rest of the calls then. And no, I don't think that flow analysis could reliably reveal that only one thread is accessing the static variable. This is definitly a non-trivial problem, harder then other non-trivial problems.

Comment: @towi I agree this is a difficult area. FWIW, I don't think threading should ever have been added to the standard.

Comment: @Neil: Oh??? Leave it unsolved? Nonono. This *had* to be dealt with. Multithreading *is* realworld. This would have left the battlefield to those other languages. Like *Java*. Or worse... ;-)

Comment: @Neil: The flow analysis would have to be aware of every piece of code run since startup, and that just isn't possible under the C++ compilation model, or on real systems with dynamic libraries.  Threading in the standard is fine, but statics should have been left unsafe by default (according to "you don't pay for what you don't use") with an accompanying library solution for easy portable threadsafe one-time initialization.

Comment: @towi I've been writing MT 24/7 servers in C++ for the past 15 years. I'm quite confident that I can do it without language features, which may in fact get in in the way, as is arguably the case here. I think the pure library approach to MT is much the best.

Comment: @Neil: The standard library is part of the standard.  I guess you meant "threading should not have been added to the *language*"?  But even that could be misread...

Comment: @Ben I meant that I didn't think that threading should be addressed by either the standard library or by specific language features. after all, database and web access is probably FAR more common in C++ code than MT, but we don't feel the need to standardise them. Or at least I hope we don't. But we are stuck with the MT stuff now, obviously.

Comment: Pure library implementations can't solve the fundamental problem with threading, that we need some kind of guarantee of what happens before what. The core language semantics have to define that. The language needed to define a memory model.